# Ejabberd Voip with mod_jinglenodes

Tags: erlang, voip, ejabberd

I was installed mod_jinglenodes.erl plugin method in ejabberd.it shown in psi+ service discovery option jinglenodes.192.168.1.35 ,but didnot get any correct response for iq

a) send iq:

```
 <iq type="get" to="kumar@192.168.1.35" id="ab71a"><servicesxmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/jinglenodes'/></iq>
```

receive it:

```
<iq from="kumar@192.168.1.35" type="error" xml:lang="en" to="babu@192.168.1.35/Psi+" id="ab71a">
<services xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/jinglenodes"/>
<error type="cancel" code="503">
<service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
</iq>
```

b)

```
<channel xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/jinglenodes#channel'  
protocol='udp'/>
```

didnot get any result.

please help me. and how to send voip call IQ example ?

Comment: How did you install the ejabberd_mod_jinglenodes ? when i run ./configure I  get the error: configure: error: ejabberd.hrl is required. Make sure PREFIX is the same as the PREFIX at which ejabberd is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the protocol examples in [XEP-0278](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0278.html), it looks like you're supposed to send the `<services>` request either to your own server (in this case `192.168.1.35`), or to the *full* JID of a contact, in this case presumably `kumar@192.168.1.35/Psi+`, but *not* to a bare JID as in your sample above, `kumar@192.168.1.35`.

Comment: ya its working good:)) but did not trigger jinglemodules ..the request sent direct to client and get response.but didnot go to jinglemodule namespace

Comment: @KumaravelSelvaraj, I'd suggest opening a new question, with a complete transcript of the stanzas exchanged between the clients.